# Can't get the size of numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
  version  count region      listing
2      v2      2    CAN     [7, 8]
2      v3      3    CAN  [7, 8, 9]
```

I want to extract `listing` list for each row and get the length. So I did the following:

```
group_v2_list = group[group['version'] == 'v2']['listing'].values
```

and I get output as `[list([7, 8])]`. Here the type of `listing` column is `numpy.ndarray` which I get after using `type(group_v2_list)`.

Now I want to get the number of elements in this `group_v2_list` but I am unable to get it.

I tried `len(group_v2_list)` and `group_v2_list.size` but both are giving me `1`. I want to get the number of elements which should be `2` as `7, 8`.

How can I get that?

Comment: You are getting the correct size of that array.  It has just one element (dtype is `object`).  That element is a list, as clearly indicated in the `output`.

Comment: @hpaulj: Yeah I understood that but I want to get the number of the elements in that object and I am not sure how to get it. Could you please suggest me some ideas here?

Comment: Try `len(group_v2_list.item())`. This takes the list out of the array, and lets you take its `len`

Comment: @hpaulj: You are awesome. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to access the `numpy` representation for this.

One way is to use `.loc` accessor to extract the series and find the length of the first element:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'version': ['v2', 'v3'],
                   'count': [2, 3],
                   'region': ['CAN', 'CAN'],
                   'listing': [[7, 8], [7, 8, 9]]})

df_v2_list = df.loc[df['version'] == 'v2', 'listing']

res_v2 = len(df_v2_list[0])
# 2
```

If there are multiple elements in your filtered data, you can retrieve a list of their lengths by using `pd.Series.map(len)`:

```
df_v_all_list = df.loc[df['version'].str.startswith('v'), 'listing']

res_all = df_v_all_list.map(len).tolist()
# [2, 3]
```